# Tokenize Words separated by non-word characters exept single quote

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

I have the following method I'm trying to implement: parses the input into “word tokens”: sequences of word characters separated by non-word characters. However, non-word characters can become part of a token if they are quoted (in single quotes).
         I want to use regex but have trouble getting my code just right:

```
public static List<String> wordTokenize(String input) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("\\b(?:(?<=\')[^\']*(?=\')|\\w+)\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher (input);
    ArrayList ans = new ArrayList();
    while (matcher.find ()){
        ans.add (matcher.group ());
    }
    return ans;
}
```

My regex fails to identify that starting a word mid word without space doesn't mean starting a new word. Examples:

1. The input: this-string 'has only three tokens' // works
2. The input: 
   "this*string'has only two@tokens'"
                      Expected :[this, stringhas only two@tokens]
                      Actual   :[this, string, has only two@tokens]
3. The input: "one'two''three' '' four 'twenty-one'"
     Expected :[onetwothree, , four, twenty-one]
   Actual   :[one, two, three, four, twenty-one]

How do I fix the spaces?

Comment: Maybe try switching with \\w?
Focus more on the "word"

Comment: I prefer to focus on my solution rather that start one from scratch

Comment: `@` is a non-word character, so I don't understand your expected output in your second case.

Comment: because it's inside of the ' ' it's fine that it wasn't separated. the problem is that it separated things that has not space and no special characters mid word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to match one or more occurrences of a word char or a substring between the closest single straight apostrophes, and remove all those apostrophes from the tokens.

Use the following regex and `.replace("'", "")` on the matches:

```
(?:\w|'[^']*')+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Voezsy/2). Details:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `\w` - a word char
  - `|` - or
  - `'` - a straight single quotation mark
  - `[^']*` - any 0+ chars other than a straight single quotation mark
  - `'` - a straight single quotation mark
- `)+` - end of the group, 1+ occurrences.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/B1n5iL):

```
// String s = "this*string'has only two@tokens'"; // => [this, stringhas only two@tokens]
String s = "one'two''three' '' four 'twenty-one'"; // => [onetwothree, , four, twenty-one]
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\w|'[^']*')+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    tokens.add(matcher.group(0).replace("'", "")); 
}
```

Note the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` is added for the `\w` pattern to match all Unicode letters and digits.